# Installing numpy on Red Hat 6?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, installation, rhel6

I'm trying to install numpy on a Red Hat (RHEL6) 64-bit linux machine that has Python 2.7. I downloaded and untar'd numpy 1.6.2 from Sourceforge, and I did the following commands in the numpy-1.6.2 folder:

```
python ./setup.py build
sudo python ./setup.py install #without sudo, this gives a permissions error.
```

Then, when I do `import numpy` on the Python prompt, I get `ImportError: No module named numpy`.

I read somewhere that numpy 1.6.2 is for Python 3.x, so I also tried the above steps with numpy 1.5.1, and I got the same `ImportError`.

I'm speculating that the solution lies in some environment variable gymnastics, but I'm not sure what files/directories Python needs to "see" that isn't in scope. Any suggestions for how to get numpy working?

I also tried some precompiled binaries for RHEL, but they gave various errors when I did `sudo yum install [numpy precompiled binary url].rpm`.

As an aside, my motivation for installing numpy is to use [PyGnuplot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygnuplot/). Also, I've installed numpy and PyGnuplot on other machines before, but it's been on Ubuntu and Mac OS.

Comment: copy and paste the output of 
import sys
print sys.path

Comment: Here's the output of `import sys` `print sys.path`: ['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: if numpy is installed correctly it should be in dist-packages, can you check and see it it's installed there ?

Comment: Wow -- pyGnuplot?  I didn't think anyone used that other than me ... I'm glad you like it.  What gets printed during the `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` phases?

Comment: Just a quick check of the simplest solution: are you sure that numpy is not available through the Red Hat package manager and your repositories?

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of python installed?  How are you launching python?

Comment: numpy 1.6.2 definitely works with python 2.7 - I'm currently using this combination. You must have been confused by the fact that recent versions of numpy work with both 2.x and 3.x lines.

Comment: @mgilson, here's the output from `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`: http://pastebin.com/j6eZN7U5

Comment: @Marius Not that I know of. `yum search numpy` doesn't give any matches. I'm pretty new to RHEL, and I've noticed that a lot of stuff is missing from wherever `yum` looks for packages, but I can sometimes find the rpms online. No such luck so far, though.

Comment: @mgilson waaait, you're the creator of PyGnuplot! Awesome! I used PyGnuplot a lot (on an ubuntu machine) last year. I wrote a Python script that did a bunch of data analysis and then generated a bunch of PyGnuplot figures. I used the figures in a research paper that will (hopefully) be published soon. :)

Comment: @solvingPuzzles Looking at the output from `setup.py`, it looks like Numpy has been installed (possibly unsuccessfully) for Python 2.6, not 2.7. Try running `python2.6` (or similar), then importing numpy.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I gave up on using RedHat, and I installed Ubuntu in a VM. It was a one-liner using `apt-get`.

Not an ideal solution to the question at hand, but I just didn't want to spend any more time chasing down a solution for RedHat.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL6 ships numpy 1.4.1, see [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat&pkglist=true&version=rhel-6.7#pkglist). If 1.4.1 is new enough for you, you can install it with:

```
$ yum install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

When I install Python packages on Ubuntu using setup.py packages end up in

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

assuming Python2.7

If numpy is installed there, you will need to append this path to your Python's path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

you can append it permentanly using ~/.profile

Another way is by adding a .pth to a directory that’s already on Python’s path, for example

```
echo "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/" > /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dist_pkg.pth
```

run that last command as root of course

Comment: After doing the installation procedure discussed in the original post, I don't have `dist-packages` in my `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` directory.

Comment: you could try installing using verbose sudo python ./setup.py --verbose install and see where the package is installed then use the same procedure to add the path.